# How to Place Model FULLY on Top of Plane?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, model, raycasting

i want to instantiate a GameObject That contains model/models as children, and i want to place it fully on top of a plane. (the whole Model)

the possible solution is to loop through the children and use Renderer.Bounds.y .and find the highest bound from them and offset the placment on the y axis by this value.

but this method is not granted to work and might not be efficient if there is a lot of sub objects

any idea how to implement this ? any idea how unity implement this on the editor when i drag the model into the scene ?

Comment: Ctr+shift and drag the object. Depending on whether you have pivot or center enabled, it should place model fully on top of the plane

Comment: @Kale_Surfer_Dude i want to instantiate and place it at runtime via script

Comment: Using bounds is probably the best way, or precache the correct value and use that at runtime